# Weird run-time 1004 error with strings in excel vba

Tags: string, excel, vba

i'm having a weird issue trying to write out this very simple vba method

This works fine :

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analyse").Cells(i, 2) = "=HiGuys"
```

This works fine :

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analyse").Cells(i, 2) = "=VLOOKUP"
```

But this gets a "Run Time error '1004' while it shouldn't. I'm going crazy with this !

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analyse").Cells(i, 2) = "=VLOOKUP("
```

Am i missing something obvious here ... ?

thanks a lot !

Comment: Writing one string or a different one to a cell does not trigger a 1004 error. You are doing something else. Please, post your whole code if you want to get some help.

Comment: @varocarbas. Yes you can. He's making an incomplete formula.

Comment: @Makah ?! Excuse me?! A 1004 error is provoked by writing a wrong formula? VBA does not care about what you put between "" and it is a VBA error. Please, delete this answer because it is clearly wrong.

Comment: @varocarbas You need to put "'" before the "=" to transform formula in text.

Comment: Apparently, Makah was (partially) right; the way in which you are inputting the string is triggering a 1004 error. I haven't ever seen this before. It seems to be provoked by the combination "=" and "(" (it might be ")" or "[" or "]").

Comment: Actually you were showing the exact problem in your question, sorry about that, I didn't realised about it and just assumed that you were doing things wrongly (+1 to compensate my lack of trust :)). I usually test the exact conditions but a 1004 error tends to be pretty evident and I wouldn't ever expect it to be triggered in such a situation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are. :-)

You code

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analyse").Cells(i, 2) = "=VLOOKUP("
```

it's iqual to

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analyse").Cells(i, 2).Formula = "=VLOOKUP("
```

And you can't make an incomplete formula in Excel. If you want to write just the string "=VLOOKUP(" you can do:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analyse").Cells(i, 2) = "'=VLOOKUP("
```

[With ' before everything ]

If you want to make a real formula, you need to complete it, like

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analyse").Cells(i, 2).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A1,A:C,2,False)"
```

Comment: What you are saying does not make any sense. He is not relying on "formula", but just writing a value to a cell (while writing it, VBA does not even know that it is a formula). Even in case of writing a formula, you wouldn't be getting a 1004 error. This is provoked, most likely, because of intending to access an non-instantiated object, either ThisWorkbook or "Analyse" sheet does not exist or i is getting a value below 1. Next time, please, before writing an answer test it.

Comment: Yes, i would expect vba not knowing it is a formula when he is supposed to write it in the excel sheet. But weirdly enough, the content of the string it is supposed to copy triggers or not an error. Hence my three examples: "=VLOOKUPHELLOGUYS" works and "=VLOOKUPHELLOGUYS(" i.E with the bracket triggers the error message. I'm going crazy with this !

Comment: @varocarbas. Sorry for the rudeness. Try ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = "=VLOOKUP(". I get the same 1004 error (Excel 2010)

Comment: You are (surprisingly) right; but it does trigger this error only under certain conditions. I do apologise and will do more tests to come to the bottom of all this.

Comment: ;-). It's the same problem when you write a wrong formula in a cell without vba.

Comment: Very, very curious... if you type "=", anything (can be a function or any random string) and a bracket (opening or closing one, normal or squared bracket), it triggers this error while writing to a cell? If you write "=VLOOKUP" does not happen nothing. if you write "=VLOOKUP(" the error is triggered; if you write "=anything(" the error is triggered, etc. Really curious!

Comment: No, it is not the same than when you write a wrong formula. You have to put together the two characters triggering the problem (equal and bracket), otherwise it does not happen. It is a VBA "bug" which I haven't ever seen.

Comment: But isn't automatically write formulas in excel one of the main purposes of VBA? I don't know what to do now.
(i'm using vba to automatically detect another 'article' in my 10000 line long set of data, and use the correct excel formula to it.)

BTW it didn't seem to trigger the same error with the =average(B1:B9) function...

Comment: @Malcoolm "But isn't automatically write formulas in excel one of the main purposes of VBA?" -> NO, at all. Actually, this is one of the first errors of Excel users coming to VBA. VBA capabilities are much higher than any Excel formula. Better: both tools give answer to different problems. Excel formulae to "static situations"; VBA to dynamic ones. You can use Excel formulae from VBA but it is usually disadvised: in most of the cases, there is a better VBA alternative.

Comment: @Malcoolm "I don't know what to do now" -> please get the ideas rightly. What you have shown here is a weird error, but nothing which should affect a proper code (if you write the formula correctly, the error would not happen). Also if you need to use formulae so much I am not sure about the exact point of moving to VBA. Anyway... don't worry; just do things rightly and everything will work properly.

Comment: @ varocarbas In that case, what is the better alternative ?
I have a 10000 line long list in excel, that concern about 350 different types of articles and every line corresponds to when a particular article was used and how much. I'd like to make basic calculations to reveal absolute deviation and standard deviation of the use of every type of article. I'm currently using vba to **detect** a change in article in the long list, and fill-in formula columns on the side to get statistics concerning the use of every type of article.

Comment: @Malcoolm If you have 10000 lines with any values and you want to perform any kind of calculations over these values, rely on Excel Formulae (unless having to do really complex calculations). If the values of these cells change, the formulae would take this into account. Formulae would take care of this almost immediately, VBA would take an appreciable amount of time (100000 are too many for VBA). When I said dynamic behaviour I meant, changing conditions. Example: if you want to get the result of A1 + B1 use a formula; if you want to get the result of (A1 or A2 or A3) + (B1 or B2 or B3)...

Comment: @Malcoolm... and the determination of each cell (A1 or A2 or, etc.) depends on complex conditions (for example: the number of rows in column X which have a value which matches the number of files in folder Y, etc.), rely on VBA. Or better: if what you want to accomplish, can easily be done by using Excel formulae, use Excel formulae; if what you want to do provokes the generation of miles-long Excel formulae or cannot even be done with Excel formulae, use VBA.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some level of "protection" involved:

```
Sub asdf()
    ActiveCell.Value = "=VLOOKUP("
End Sub
```

will throw a "1004", but:

```
Sub asdf2()
    ActiveCell.Value = "=VLOOKUP"
End Sub
```

will not.

This is analogous to how the worksheet responds if you try to manually enter the bad formula.